# Problem with nuxt-links navigation to pages with hashes/anchors

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, nuxt.js

I am using nuxt-links in my website navigation, most of them point to hashed elements/anchors in the home page like:

```
<nuxt-link
  v-else
  class="text-link"
  :to="localePath('index') + #hash"
>
```

and it does its job if currently on the home page but when I navigate to a different site, eg. /about and I click on a navbar nuxt-link (so I want to navigate from /about to /#hash or /any-other-site#hash) I got a nuxt error displayed to check the console where it reads "Cannot read property 'offsetTop' of null".

My router configuration in nuxt.config (without it I wouldn't be even able to scroll to an anchored element being in the same site as the element!):

```
  router: {
    scrollBehavior(to) {
      if (to.hash) {
        return window.scrollTo({ top: document.querySelector(to.hash).offsetTop + window.innerHeight, behavior: 'smooth' });
      }
      return window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
      }
  },
```

In the :to attribute I tried 'hash' '#hash', nothing works. Could please anyone help me with this? How do I navigate to a different page + #anchor (so to scroll to that anchor?)

Comment: If you are using nuxt version 2.4+ then [this](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-router/#scrollbehavior) is how you should set up scroll behaviour, specifically the return Promise part at the bottom.

Comment: @Andrew1325 With the default configuration (the one you mention) when I click on mu nuxt links `<nuxt-link to="/#hash">` scrolling to that element never happens. Clicking does not trigger anything.

Answer (score 47):

Anyone who had this problem here is a simple solution if you are using `Nuxt-Link`

Instead of using 
`<nuxt-link to="#contact" >Contact</nuxt-link>` which doesn't work. 
Use `<nuxt-link :to="{ path: '/',hash:'#contact'}">Contact</nuxt-link>`

`path` is the page you will navigate to

`hash` is the position you will scroll to

Hope this help someone.

Comment: Just tested in version `^2.0.0` of Nuxt and that does not seem to work.

Comment: works for me on the same version @FooBar, altough It doesn't scroll to the div, it simply goes to directly to the hash. I haven't messed with the default router scroll behavior.

Comment: In Nuxt 3.0.0 it actually works: `<NuxtLink to="#contact">`

Answer (score 2):

Using this way, with **getBoundingClientRect().top+window.scrollY**, works better to me in case of subsections:

```js
if (to.hash) {
        let el = await findEl(to.hash)
        if ('scrollBehavior' in document.documentElement.style) {
          return window.scrollTo({ top: el.getBoundingClientRect().top+window.scrollY, behavior: 'smooth' })
        } else {
          return window.scrollTo(0, el.getBoundingClientRect().top+window.scrollY)
        }
      }
```

Comment: A lifesaver! A legend!

Comment: Full implementation

https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/12732#issuecomment-1397227372

Answer (score 2):

A bit late but this is what I was able to achieve. Thanks to Sivuyile-TG-Magutywa

```
 <nuxt-link :to="{ path: localePath('index'),hash:'#about'}">
          {{ $t("menu.about") }}
 </nuxt-link>
```

output

```
https://www.shrek.com/fr/about
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to attach data ID to link so :

```
<div class="col" v-for="(item, index) in category.children.slice(0, 5)" :key="index">
<nuxt-link :to="{ path: localePath('/category/'+item.slug)}" target="_blank">
```