# How do I navigate to a section on a seperate page using nuxt?

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

I am using nuxt.js in my current project, at the top I have a navbar that has drop-downs for links.  The top-level links go directly to a page (/foo).  What I would like is for the sublinks to link to a specific section (/foo/#bar).  And that is where I am struggling.  This is what I currently have.

```
<nuxt-link :to="{path:item.url,hash:link.Url}" class="dropdown-item">
                            <!-- <nuxt-link :to="link.Url" class="dropdown-item"> -->
                                {{link.Text}}
                            </nuxt-link>
```

The idea for this came from this SO answer: [Problem with nuxt-links navigation to pages with hashes/anchors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55599364/problem-with-nuxt-links-navigation-to-pages-with-hashes-anchors)

It mostly works, however, the link that it tries for is: `/foo#bar` instead of `/foo/#bar`.

Answer (score 0):

The structure of your folder should be like this.

1. Create a `foo` folder
2. Create a `foo.vue` file. This is a `<NuxtPage/>`
3. Inside the `foo` folder, create an `index.vue` file.

[image]

See stackblitz example.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-2nmpto?file=pages/index.vue

More information about the nested pages on Nuxt documentation on [Routes file tree](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/pages#nested-routes)